# Getting filesize from OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

How can I get the filesize of the currently-selected file in my Openfiledialog?

Comment: Do you mean while the dialogue is open, or after the dialogue has been closed? Do you mean for the program or for the user of the program?

Comment: I have a feeling that some interop will be needed here :-)  Nice question though BTW, Interesting

Comment: More clarification please, as per Richard's comment.

Answer (score 6):

You can't directly get it from the OpenFieldDialog.

You need to take the file path and consturct a new FileInfo object from it like this:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
```

And from the FileInto you can get the size of the file like this

```
fileInfo.Length
```

For more info look at this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) page.

Answer (score 2):

Without interop and like the first comment, once the dialogue has been complete i.e. file/s have been selected this would give the size.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (openFileDialog1.Multiselect)
                {
                    long total = 0;
                    foreach (string s in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                        total += new FileInfo(s).Length;
                    MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());


                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName).Length.ToString());
                }


            }
        }
```

File size during dialogue I feel would need to use interop

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I think there is 3 way, creating your custom open dialog or setting by code the view as detail or asking the user to use detail view

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when the dialog is running, I suspect you just change the file view to details. However if you mean programmatically I suspect that you'd have to hook a windows message when the file is selected.